# Reduce the WP setup size

Tags: wordpress, resize, reduce

I have to reduce my WP setup size, to reduce the site loading time. I have already deleted log files, backup folders, cache files, old setup folder and some other unnecessary files and folders also. I also tried some plug-ins to optimize the site, like Media Cleaner, WP-Optimize, etc. But still I have to further reduce the size, cause its facing issue while uploading the setup on Github. Do you know, how it can be reduced further...?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to check what are the heaviest directories and files in your Wordpress installation.
Are you trying to upload your website to **GitHub Pages**?
If so, you need to check their limitations regarding the usage.

##### GitHub Pages sites are subject to the following usage limits:

- GitHub Pages source repositories have a recommended limit of 1GB. For
  more information, see "[What is my disk quota?](https://docs.github.com/en/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/#file-and-repository-size-limitations)"
- Published GitHub Pages sites may be no larger than 1 GB.

https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages

In this case you might try to reduce your uploads directory by optimizing images and removing unused Image Media Sizes. There are many ways how to do it. You might take a look at this plugin [Stop Generating Unnecessary Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-sizes/)

This might help you to upload your website to GitHub.

Regarding the site loading time - this is a different thing, which is related to using cache plugins, such as **WP Fastest Cache** or **WP Super Cache**, and etc., and applying other optimizing techniques.